# Can I prevent Rails from passing instance variables from controller to view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any way to disable the automatic passing of Rails instance variables to the views when they render? I'd like to be able to turn this off and then see where things fail in order to target refactoring.

Comment: Interesting.  No idea, but maybe an after hook in the controller would let you examine any instance variables defined?  That wouldn't tell you if you were using them in the view, but if you're not using them in the view why have them at all?

Comment: very useful question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do that by overriding `view_assigns` in your controller:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  protected
   def view_assigns
   {} #an empty hash
   end
end
```

Comment: Ahhh, yes! Simple solution.

Comment: is there any way to raise an error whenever an ivar is referenced?